# Java parse page in browser

Tags: java, browser, httprequest

I would like to parse the html from a page open in a browser from a separate application. I am able to run the browser, but it does not provide anything in the input stream of the subprocess. Is there any way to download the html content of the page?

Alternatively, is there a way to monitor all HTTP requests sent and received from/to localhost without installing 3rd party software or configuring proxy for the browser? More specifically, can anyone point me in the right direction how to implement such a monitor?

Comment: Make an HTTP connection to the URL and stream the contents back. If you want to do it periodically, do it in a thread

Comment: Your browser may already have that feature to monitor all HTTP requests. For FireFox, I'm not sure if the built-in Developer has it, but the very common FireBug extension sure do.

Comment: the fact that most browsers already have a built in way to monitor requests does not help a whole lot, since there is no way (at least that I can think of) to get my application to interface with them. Opening a connection to the URL should probably work however...